# UITextField with numbers only & "done" on keyboard on the iPhone

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, numeric

I'm learning obj-c and gave myself a simple task of creation an app that has 2 `uitextfields`, `label` & `button` (button summarizes 2 numbers and shows the result in label). I made this app but I haven't figured out how to make `textfields` interact with "done" button & "numbers only" together.

Below is my code:

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property NSInteger textFieldInt1, textFieldInt2;
@property NSString *textFieldStr1, *textFieldStr2;

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;

@end


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label, textField1, textField2, textFieldInt1, textFieldInt2, textFieldStr1, textFieldStr2;

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    textFieldInt1=[textField1.text integerValue];
    textFieldInt2=[textField2.text integerValue];
    label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", textFieldInt1+textFieldInt2];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.textField1 setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [self.textField2 setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

}

-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(![string intValue] && ![string isEqualToString:@""] && ![string isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
    return NO;
    } else {
    return YES;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


@end
```

Also I connected (in storyboard) both `textFields` to `hideKeyboard (didEndOnExit)`, and `button` to `button (touchUpInside)` and all outlets (`textfields`, `button`, `label`).

**The problem is:** `numbers only` input doesn't work with `done`. If I use `delegate` (new referencing outlet in storyboard connected to both `textfields`) I get `numbers only` input in `textfields` but the `done` button doesn't work (when I press it on the iPhone nothing happens). If I don't use `delegate` I get `all characters` input but `done` works fine (when I press it iPhone keyboard hides).

Any suggestions what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
// This is how we get rid of the keyboard.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    //Do whatever you need to to save etc...
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

This tells the keyboard to hide when the done button is pressed.
Be sure to set your view controller as the textfields' delegate:
    myTextField.delegate = self;
(probably in viewDidLoad)

Comment: This was a comment responding to a comment someone posted and then deleted.  Since the original comment is gone, and I can't delete this comment, you get this trash comment....great.

Comment: I'm sorry for my english, probably I didn't make my question clear enough. I do have "done" button and it works correctly (hides keyboard) but without using "numbers only"input restriction. And that is the problem I can't solve.

Comment: thank you a lot! It works fine! I've replaced my method (IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {[self.view endEditing:YES];} with yours and associated both textfields with "delegate" (new referencing outlets).